# Azure functions app and runtimeStack for node

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-function-app

When deploying to an Azure functions app using the devops task AzureFunctionApp@1, there is an option to supply a runtimeStack. When I choose JavaScript it automatically inserts the runtimeStack as shown below

```
 - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
      runtimeStack: 'DOCKER|microsoft/azure-functions-node8:2.0'
```

My linux functions app is running node 12/runtime 3.0 and the deployment is zip. This is inserted as node8 and runtime 2.0. Is this correct? It doesn't match the version I am using but the Azure editor highlights it as an error if I change it to anything else.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here, but looks like this is a bug in the azure tasks UI and will be fixed soon

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/commit/ae348864ae539a2c84c49b1e6bd499ce92b90356